# How to Convert Http Url into rtsp Url

Tags: android

How do I convert a HTTP URL into a RTSP URL?

Comment: Weird question :) replace http with rtsp I guess.

Comment: Do you want to be able to stream or to just replace http string with rtsp?

Comment: The http url is coming from youtube rss without file format (for eg. .mp4,.3gp), but no rtsp url found on youtube rss.

Answer (score 0):

To employ a RTSP url you need to have an RTSP server. It will be easier to give you a productive reply if you give us a little more information on what you are trying to do?